# How to create a listview which has 2 list items for each row

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a listview of which the listitems only needs half (or less) of your screen, so two items can be displayed next to each other. I can't find any examples on the internet. Does someone know how this can be done?

I want to create something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpGrs.jpg

Comment: This is made using GridView. Do you want that?

Comment: @Doc That's what i needed, thank you!

Comment: i sample can be found on https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/08/flutter-gridview-builder-example.html

Answer (score 0):

This example may be helpful for your problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp(
    items: List<ListItem>.generate(
      1000,
      (i) => i % 6 == 0 ? HeadingItem("Heading $i") : MessageItem("Sender $i", "Message body $i"),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ListItem> items;

  MyApp({Key key, @required this.items}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Mixed List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final item = items[index];

            if (item is HeadingItem) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  item.heading,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                ),
              );
            } else if (item is MessageItem) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(item.sender),
                subtitle: Text(item.body),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

abstract class ListItem {}

class HeadingItem implements ListItem {
  final String heading;

  HeadingItem(this.heading);
}

class MessageItem implements ListItem {
  final String sender;
  final String body;

  MessageItem(this.sender, this.body);
}
```